# Wrong url scheme for WebSocket

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0

I have a websockets program in play 2.1, which works just fine and the template looks like this:

```
// Contents of the view.scala.html file
@(userName: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)

@main("text") {
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket;
    alert("before")
    var socket = new WS("@routes.Application.view(userName).webSocketURL()");
    alert("after")
    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
      alert(event.data);
    };
  });
  </script>
}
```

The issue is that as soon as I move my javascript into the `assets.javascripts` folder and change the `view.scala.html` file into the following it stops working.

```
// Contents of the view.scala.html file
@(userName: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)

@main("text") {
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
          src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/viewer.min.js")"></script>
}
```

Play finds the file, executes the javascript, I can see the popup triggered by the `alert("before")` line of code, but after that... nothing.

This is the google chrome error I get in the console:

```
Wrong url scheme for WebSocket
http://localhost:9000/@routes.Application.view(userName).webSocketURL()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you really intend to support Firefox 6 and 7? Those are dead since a long time and NOT extended-support releases. What I'm trying to say... you can most likely get rid of the `MozWebSocket` part.

Comment: I'm a web noobie, just copied this from one of the examples on the web. So I guess the answer to your question is "not really, no" ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A WebSocket needs `ws://` or `wss://` (for SSL) instead of `http://`.

However, the problem in your code is that the statement `@routes.Application.view(userName).webSocketURL()` apparently isn't replaced with some useful value but kept as-is. This is because your framework seems to consider assets completely static and thus ignores anything in there that would be a placeholder/variable in a normal template.

One possible solution for your problem would be keeping the URL in your template, e.g. by adding `data-ws="@....."` to your `<body>` tag and then use JavaScript to extract that attribute:

```
var socket = new WebSocket(document.body.getAttribute('data-ws'))
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the "all static" part, because the `userName` is also a placeholder/variable and I can indeed print it our from javascript.

Comment: That's not inside a file in your assets folder, is it?

Comment: Well the userName is the variable for the template and I can access it from javascript, both from the assets folder or directly of course. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: I just noticed that I was targeting an html span with an id of "userName" and not the userName variable passed into the template. So you might be right after all.

Comment: My solution is as follows: template code `<div id="user" data-ws="@routes.Application.view(userName).webSocketURL()">` js code `var socket = new WS($('#user').data('ws'));`

Answer (score 2):

I used the following :

> ```
>   ws=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/websocket/wsserver");
> ```

Thanks.